# How to work responsive email

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email

I did a post about this yesterday. With the help of one answer, I learned the good structure for an email newsletter. I applied those on my email newsletter. I also added media query code. I know, media query is not supported in all email clients. But, Who support, I want some change with layout for them. Unfortunately, media queries haven't worked in my email newsletter, I can't understand what's the reason. This is the visual of [desktop version email](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YYZXe/3/). This is the visual of [mobile version email](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/4Dwny/1/). Basically, **main difference** is on the **four columns**.

1. At mobile, there will  be two columns instead of four columns.
2. As last two columns will be placed below the first two columns, last two columns should have spacing from top. So, the above two columns' and below two columns' border(vertical line) can't touch
3. And at desktop version, every columns have border-right property except last one. At mobile, second and fourth column should not have border-right property

To do that, I've arranged my code this way:

1. There is four columns at visual below logo. Basically, those are two separate table contains two columns each. The parent table's `width="640"`. The child table's `width="320"` The first child table is `align="left"` So, the two child tables are placed in a row nicely. My intend is make the main table's `width="320"` for mobile, so the two child tables can't be placed in a row.
2. I've given `padding-top: 20px` to second child table for mobile. So, that table can get some space from above table.
3. As, second and last column have no right-border property, I have called a class on that for mobile and given them `border: 0;`

Inside head code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Email</title>
<style>
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    table[class="mainTable"] {
        width: 320px !important;
    }
    table[class="subTable"] {
        padding: 20px 0 0 !important;   
    }
    td[class="noBorder"] {
        border: 0 !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Inside Body Code:

```
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mainTable" style="margin: 0px auto; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 35px 0 0;">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 25px;">
                LOGO
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="left" width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 15px 0 15px; width: 160px; height: 150px; border-right: 1px solid #666;">
                            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 5px 0 10px;">Remaining</p>
                            <p style="font-size: 35px; margin: 0 0 20px;">12d, 17hr</p>
                            <a style="background: #ccc; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 10px;" href="#">Visit</a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="noBorder" style="padding: 15px 0 15px; width: 160px; height: 150px; border-right: 1px solid #666;">
                            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 5px 0 10px;">Remaining</p>
                            <p style="font-size: 35px; margin: 0 0 20px;">12d, 17hr</p>
                            <a style="background: #ccc; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 10px;" href="#">Visit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="subTable" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 15px 0 15px; width: 160px; height: 150px; border-right: 1px solid #666;">
                            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 5px 0 10px;">Remaining</p>
                            <p style="font-size: 35px; margin: 0 0 20px;">12d, 17hr</p>
                            <a style="background: #ccc; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 10px;" href="#">Visit</a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 15px 0 15px; width: 160px; height: 150px;">
                            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 5px 0 10px;">Remaining</p>
                            <p style="font-size: 35px; margin: 0 0 20px;">12d, 17hr</p>
                            <a style="background: #ccc; color: #000; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px 10px;" href="#">Visit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But, this doesn't work for me. At mobile, I've seen no change according to my code. I've checked at android Gmail app(may be, it's not supporting media query). At there, four columns automatically go to the two columns in a two row, but spacing and border haven't worked. I've also checked to Sony android default Email app(It should be support media query). At there, there is no changed happened! It shows exactly same way how the desktop shows. Besides Android device, I haven't any other mobile device for checking :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make table email newsletter to responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823194/how-to-make-table-email-newsletter-to-responsive)

Comment: According to [this](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/) the Android Gmail app does not support media queries. [Here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is another site with details on what clients support what CSS features.

Comment: yes, main things are duplicate. I've post that yesterday. But the coding of yesterday and today is not same. Yesterday's code is not good. So, media query couldn't apply to that. Someone gave links to comment. I followed them and try to code my email on that way. After doing everything right today, My media query code is not working. That's why, I want help why it's not working and how can be made it working

Comment: It is good practice to update your original question with a "here is what I have so far" type edit instead of posting something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make a responsive email is pretty much still a waste of time and effort due to the amount of email clients which will ignore and/or strip out your code.

HTML emails should basically be coded like it is 1999 with tables, images, some basic inline styles etc.

If it must be responsive try just removing the width from your tables and allowing them to be naturally responsive.

Here's a good resource on tips for HTML emails:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

Comment: Yes, I coded it like 1999 styles. Everything is good. Just media query is not working. I want to make sure my media query will work on that device which support it

Comment: Bunch of resources on [responsive and fluid email techniques and templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/html-email-best-practices-considerations-and-how-to-write-code-for-outlook-gma/21437734#21437734) here.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer I posted the other day (the deleted dupe), pretty sure I linked you to [this basic responsive example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614437/html-email-looking-different-in-gmail-app/22615527#22615527).

You haven't applied the `display:block;` toggle. Your email section should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { .switch { width:100%; display:block; } }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" class="switch">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding:30px;" bgcolor="#333333">
            Cell 1
          </td>
          <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding:30px;" bgcolor="#444444">
            Cell 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="50%" class="switch">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding:30px;" bgcolor="#555555">
            Cell 3
          </td>
          <td width="50%" valign="top" style="padding:30px;" bgcolor="#666666">
            Cell 4
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Yes, I haven't applied display: block; but, you took display: block, so that that td can fill the 100% width. But, in my code no td need to fill 100% width. If my main table's width is less than 640, the last two column(second child table) will go down automatically. And if the main table's width is 320px, the two child table fill the full width of it's parent automatically. I've showed it at jsfiddle already. That's why, I want to set my main table's width 320px for mobile only. Besides this, I've applied border: 0 for mobile which isn't working too. That's means no media query is working

Comment: And, the saddest thing is I can't check in a device which can support media query. I've only a sony android device. If you kindly can show me a way to work at least a simple media query at my email, I'll be able to change any kind of layout for mobile then.

Comment: I have changed color code for mobile device at media query code. That's can't get by mobile too. So, today my problem is, no media query is working!!!

Comment: You need the `display:block;` as well, otherwise even though you have the widths right, it will try and make the `<td>`'s next to each other (the default behavior), busting the parent table to fit all sibling `<td>`'s. Also, 100% is only 100% of the parent container. It is easier than writing exact pixel amounts and will also work if you are going to make it fluid between media query break points. If you want to test, sign up for a 7 day trial of Litmus.

Comment: hi, I've figured out why no media query is working at my email. The point is I used "@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" instead of "@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)". I've fixed this line and now my media query is working! How stupid I was!