# Responsive email template Outlook displaying issue

Tags: html, email, outlook

Can someone look at the below codes and tell me what I did wrong ? I am testing the my template on litmus and everything seems perfect but when I send a test email to my outlook account the template displaying very messy. Thanks in advance. Below you can find the product table codes.

```
<!-- * PRODUCT TABLE * -->
        <table mc:repeatable="productfourgrid" mc:variant="productfourgrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="producttable" width="600" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- * PRODUCT 2 TABLE * -->
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="product" width="297">

                <tr>
                    <td>

                    <!-- * PRODUCT 1 * -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="product" width="144">

                        <!-- * PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                            <td align="center"><img mc:edit="productimage1" class="productimg" src="images/product1.png" alt="Image Alt Here" title="Image Title Here"/></td>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="productdescription1" align="center" style="font-size:13px; line-height:150%;"><strong>Makita:</strong> Boremaskine med slag. 12V.</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRICE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="price1" align="center" style="font-size:18px;">DKK 499,00</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRICE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * BUTTON HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img mc:edit="button1" src="images/button.png" alt="Button Alt Here" title="Button Title Here"/></a></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF BUTTON HERE * -->

                    </table>
                    <!-- * END OF PRODUCT 1 * -->

                    <!-- * PRODUCT 2 * -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="product" width="144">

                        <!-- * PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                            <td align="center"><img mc:edit="productimage2" class="productimg" src="images/product2.png" alt="Image Alt Here" title="Image Title Here"/></td>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="productdescription2" align="center" style="font-size:13px; line-height:150%;"><strong>Makita:</strong> Boremaskine med slag. 12V.</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRICE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="price2" align="center" style="font-size:18px;">DKK 499,00</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRICE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * BUTTON HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img mc:edit="button2" src="images/button.png" alt="Button Alt Here" title="Button Title Here"/></a></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF BUTTON HERE * -->

                    </table>
                    <!-- * END OF PRODUCT 2 * -->
                </td>
                </tr>  
               </table>  

      <!-- * PRODUCT 2 TABLE * -->   

       <!-- * PRODUCT 2 TABLE * -->
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="product" width="297">  

                <tr>
                    <td>

                    <!-- * PRODUCT 3 * -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="product" width="144">

                        <!-- * PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                            <td align="center"><img mc:edit="productimage3" class="productimg" src="images/product3.png" alt="Image Alt Here" title="Image Title Here"/></td>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="productdescription3" align="center" style="font-size:13px; line-height:150%;"><strong>Makita:</strong> Boremaskine med slag. 12V.</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRICE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="price3" align="center" style="font-size:18px;">DKK 499,00</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRICE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * BUTTON HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img mc:edit="button3" src="images/button.png" alt="Button Alt Here" title="Button Title Here"/></a></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF BUTTON HERE * -->

                    </table>
                    <!-- * END OF PRODUCT 3 * -->

                    <!-- * PRODUCT 4 * -->
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="product" width="144">

                        <!-- * PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                            <td align="center"><img mc:edit="productimage4" class="productimg" src="images/product4.png" alt="Image Alt Here" title="Image Title Here"/></td>
                            <td width="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT IMAGE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                            <td height="10"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="productdescription4" align="center" style="font-size:13px; line-height:150%;"><strong>Makita:</strong> Boremaskine med slag. 12V.</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT DESCRIPTION HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * PRICE HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td mc:edit="price4" align="center" style="font-size:18px;">DKK 499,00</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF PRICE HERE * -->

                        <!-- * TOP SPACER * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                            <td height="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF TOP SPACER * -->

                        <!-- * BUTTON HERE * -->
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank"><img mc:edit="button4" src="images/button.png" alt="Button Alt Here" title="Button Title Here"/></a></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- * END OF BUTTON HERE * -->

                    </table>
                    <!-- * END OF PRODUCT 4 * -->
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>

              </td>
           </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- * PRODUCT 2 TABLE * -->   

        <!-- * END OF PRODUCT TABLE * -->
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the messy-ness? Are one of your aligned tables bumping down?

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Yes exactly 2 of my aligned tables bumping down. I can not import images as I need at least 10 reputation on here =)

Comment: +1. Now you have 10 reputation.

Comment: Here it is. Thank you very much! http://s29.postimg.org/byakpabpj/screen_shot_4.jpg

Comment: The product table has 4 grid products but right table which contains 2 products in it also bumping down..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see what fixes it:

1. Set `width=""` on every `<td>` that isn't in a row by itself. Outlook has issues with widths when not specified.
2. Try using table cells instead of placing the tables as siblings. I see you've allowed extra space in your table widths, but you can avoid it this way. If you need it to be responsive, from your media query you can toggle `display:block; width:100%;` on the `<td>`'s to get them to overflow to the next line. Basic [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842611/how-to-work-responsive-email/22843485#22843485).
3. Try setting widths on your images, the default height might be causing an issue.
4. Put `&nbsp;` in all empty cells so they don't collapse.

You also don't need the colspan on the first row - I doubt that makes a difference, but good to keep it clean when debugging. Let me know how that goes.